# Wordpress Embed plugin admin page into custom php page

Tags: wordpress

I'm using slimstat wordpress plugin and i have a custom php page called `custom-dashboard.php` .  Slimstat has an admin page called `overview`, which has an overview of the website statistics.

I would like to display the contents of this page on `custom-dashboard.php`.

Comment: I was thinking of an iframe but that would include all of wordpress menu and header.

Comment: have you removed all the dashboard widgets ?

Answer (score 0):

Find in the slimstat plugin where the "overview" page is created (I'm not familiar with this plugin, so you're on your own with that one, sorry).

Then, throw a simple php include in there:

```
<?php include(dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/custom-dashboard.php');?>
```